# Shell string manipulation

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, freebsd

I am using an old (7.3) version of FreeBSD, so I can't use length, substr, index, or match arguments of `expr` command.
I want to extract the fourth word from the command's output (without a script). I actually can do this by using backticks, or a pipe, but I'll have to use a script, which only contains `echo $4`. That's kind of awkward. Which command would you suggest to use to parse an input string from another command? I heard of `awk` and `sed`, but I'm unsure if they are those which I need.

Comment: what version of bash do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use:

```
fourth_word=$(your_command | awk '{print $4}')
```

as in the following transcript:

```
pax> fourth_word=$(echo ab cd ef gh ij | awk '{print $4}')
pax> echo $fourth_word
gh
```